# RestTemplate With Bearer Authorization Works In Postman But Fails on Spring 401 Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, api

I'm trying to call an api. In postman it's working fine, but when Java calls the same endpoint, passing the same arguments isn't working, because I take the 401 error (unauthorized)
Even more strange is the fact that if I fill the token as String (note that is the same token that I'm retrieving of method) it's working.
Any idea whats is the problem?

```
private String getAccessToken() throws Exception {

    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost requestToken = new HttpPost("https://example.com/login");
    
    String json = "{\"login\":\"john\",\"pass\":\"hello\"}";
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
    requestToken.setEntity(entity);
    requestToken.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    requestToken.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(requestToken);
    
    String responseString = new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response);
    
    return responseString;
}

public void getEmployees()  {
    try {
        String accessToken = getAccessToken();
        System.out.println(accessToken); //prints "foo"
        
        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        //headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);  //don't work: 401 error
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + "foo"); //works
        
        
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>("body", headers);
        String url = "https://example.com/employees";
        
        ResponseEntity<String> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
        
        String content = exchange.getBody();
        
        System.out.println(content);
        
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

The stack trace error is:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:766)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:724)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:600)
at at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.doFilter(ResourceUrlEncodingFilter.java:60)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: can you add what is the stackTrace error?

Comment: here it goes ;)

Comment: Check that you don't have strange whitespace or new-line characters in the  `responseString` .

Comment: can you print the length of accessToken? System.out.println(accessToken.length());

Comment: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJOYW1lIjoiSUJNIiwicm9sZSI6WyJHZXRBZ2VuZGFtZW50byIsIlBvc3RBZ2VuZGFtZW50byIsIlB1dEFnZW5kYW1lbnRvIiwiR2V0Q2lkYWRlIiwiR2V0Q2xpZW50ZSIsIlBvc3RDbGllbnRlIiwiUHV0Q2xpZW50ZSIsIkdldENvbnRhdG8iLCJHZXREZWFsZXIiLCJQb3N0RGVhbGVyIiwiUHV0RGVhbGVyIiwiR2V0TW9kZWxDb2RlIiwiR2V0TW9kZWxvVmVpY3VsbyIsIkdldFByIiwiR2V0U2Vydmljb0RuIiwiR2V0VGlwb3NEZVNlcnZpY28iLCJHZXRUaXBvU2Vydmljb0RuIl0sInN1YiI6ImlibV9hcGkiLCJqdGkiOiI4MDM4MmU0OS02NGRhLTQ5ZGEtYjllOS0zZDczMDI5MjE0NjIiLCJleHAiOjE2NDM4NTE0NzgsImlzcyI6IkF0b3MuVnd0Yi5SZXN0In0.esOGC9eB7s0EU0dfEEUFtFDRYw4QN8SirURuCtA_oZE"  
582 (length)

Comment: @Arnaud, I also figured that but it is absolutely the same value.

Comment: @Pirate  when I fill the string that is 580 chars, but when I print the value of method it's giving 582, even with .trim(). I don't know wich char is hide here

Comment: The problem was in the double quots. When I toke the accesToken from console I thought  the double quotes was from the Java so I ignored it . A simple .replace("\"", "") in the accessToken value resolved my problem.

Comment: @oitathi I have the similar issue but I couldn't fix it. I hope you can help me . Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77077657/how-to-use-bearer-token-in-integration-test-for-mock-or-other-way-in-spring-boot